# A stupid question about constrained optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

This is taken from an example in Boas, Mathematical Methods for Physicists. The problem is to minimize the distance, $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, from the origin to the curve $y=1-x^2$. That is minimize $d$ to the constraint $y=1-x^2$. that Figure 1, shows the correct solutions. When I try to solve the problem using Langrange multipliers or other methods, I get the solutions $x=0,y=1$ or $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},y=\frac{1}{2}$. 
[image: The figure]

However, from the figure it is seems that there is also a solution at $x=\pm1,y=0$. The distance $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$ as for the point $(0,1)$ and it follows the constraint.  Why do none of the methods return that?

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: The curve $y=1-x^2$. I'll edit the question.

Comment: The points $(\pm1,0)$ are neither local minima nor local maxima of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Why do you think they are?

Comment: Something's still missing here. I see no evidence that $x=\pm 1$, $y=0$ is a solution. It is quite clear they do not minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Nor does $x=0$, $y=1$; that seems like a local maximum. Part of the problem, as I see it, is "minimize the distance $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$". Distance to *what*? The origin? That's the only interpretation that makes the formula sensible.

Comment: But for $(\pm1,0) d=1$ and it falls on the parabola. Similarly for the point $(0,1), d=1$ and it falls on the parabola. Why is then $(\pm1,0)$ not a maximum? I am sorry if this is too basic, but I think there is something very wrong with my understanding here.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant yes, it's the distance to the origin.

Comment: You said you were trying to minimize, not maximize. There  is no maximum anyway---you can get arbitrarily far from the origin.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is a local solution to the Lagrangian but ultimately it is neither a minimum or maximum.

Comment: Ah! I think I get it now. Thank you. So the point $(0,1)$ just happens to be one where the slope goes to zero, it's neither a maximum nor a minimum. It's an artifact of the method.

Comment: I would say $(0,1)$ is a *local* maximum, though not a global maximum.

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to minimize the distance from the graph of $y(x)=1-x^2$ to the origin. Recall that distance between two points is 
$$
d=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}
$$
In our case, we want the origin, $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$. So we have 
$$
d=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
But $d$ is minimal if and only if $d^2$ is minimal. It is computationally easier to minimize $d^2$, that is
$$
d^2=x^2+y^2
$$
So we minimize this instead.
$$
d^2=x^2+y^2=x^2+(1-x^2)^2=x^2+1-2x^2+x^4=x^4-x^2+1
$$
Now we take the derivative, 
$$
\frac{Dd^2}{Dx}=4x^3-2x=x(4x^2-2)
$$
Now set this equal to zero, 
$$
x(4x^2-2)=0
$$
So that $x=0$ or $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now we need to find which one of these are mins. Using the orginary first derivative test for max or mins, we find that $x=0$ is a max and $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are minimums. From symmetry, we would expect if we get one that we should get $2$. This doesn't require Lagrange multiplies at all.

Comment: Thank you for the effort in typing up the reply. But my question wasn't this. I already solved the problem (using lagrange, but I am aware that you don't need it). I am just confused why points $(\pm1,0)$ did not come up in the solution because the distance to those points is also $1$, the same as our local maximum at $(0,1)$. My confusion is very basic :(.

Comment: You said in the comments that the problem was to minimize the distance from the origin to the curve. As it stands, you are either minimizing $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, **not** necessarily a distance with the constraint $y=1-x^2$ or you are finding the minimum distance from $y=1-x^2$ to the origin. You need to be clear on the question.

Comment: They do not come up in the solution because they are not local maxima. Geometrically, they are not tangent to the objective surface (the circle with $d=1$) so they cannot be candidate solutions.

Comment: @Sujaan I don't know where you are getting those numbers. I can only assume from your plot. I see the parabola $y=1-x^2$ in the plot. But what are the circles? These are circles, not distances. I can only assume you or Matlab took a particular $d$, but $d$ varies based on the $x$ and $y$ and certainly will not look like circles when plotted for various $x,y$. Moreover, $x=0$ and $y=1$ is not a solution, it's a max not a min. So I don't know where $x=\pm 1$ is coming from. But it has nothing to do with max/mins insofar as I can tell.

Comment: Hey, sorry. The circles were just my way of visualizing the solutions. I think that's what confused me. I wasn't bothered about the solution, I got the correct answer and I really should have just gone my way. But it bothered me that the distance to the point $(0,1)$ is the same as it is to the points $(\pm1,0)$, and all three satisfy the constraint, i.e. they fall on the parabola. If one is detected as a local maximum then why are the others not detected? I finally understood why is that.

Comment: @Sujaan Ah, I finally see what you mean. Yes, the points $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ all have the same distance $d=1$ to the origin. If one of these were a minimum, then they all would be for the reason you thought. However, we can do even better at $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$, where $y=1/2$ and the distance to the origin is $\sqrt{3}/2 \approx 0.866$. Good luck with the rest of Boaz! It's a nice introduction to Mathematics for scientists.